# Action Server Compiler Error => error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_mfi

Tags: ros, action-server, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a problem about creating an action_server on ROS1. I have created a few action server programs in the past. But never get this error which i will tell the details of. My action server program is very easy:( load_action_03.cpp )

```
#include <ros/ros.h> 
#include <actionlib/server/simple_action_server.h>
#include <qr_drive/load_service_04Action.h>

//Goal angle should be a value within (-pi,pi]
class LoadActionServer
{
    
protected:
    ros::NodeHandle nh_;
    actionlib::SimpleActionServer<qr_drive::load_service_04Action> as_; // NodeHandle instance must be created before this line. Otherwise strange error occurs.
    std::string action_name_; 
    // create messages that are used to published feedback/result 
    qr_drive::load_service_04ActionFeedback feedback_; 
    qr_drive::load_service_04ActionResult result_; 

public:


  LoadActionServer(std::string name):as_(nh_,name,boost::bind(&LoadActionServer::LoadActionFunc,this,_1),false),
  action_name_(name)
  {
    as_.start() ; 
  }

  ~LoadActionServer(void);

    void LoadActionFunc(const qr_drive::load_service_04ActionGoalConstPtr &goal) 
    {
        ROS_INFO("[Load Server] LoadServiceFunc is started") ; 

        ROS_INFO("[Load_action Server] LoadServiceFunc is done") ;
    }


};

LoadActionServer::~LoadActionServer(void)
{
    std::cout << "aaaa" << std::endl ; 
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  ros::init(argc,argv,"load_action_server_node") ; 

//   LoadActionServer a_object("load_service") ; 

  ROS_INFO("Load Server is started...") ; 

  ros::spin(); 

  return 0 ; 

}
```

Related action message is below:( load_service_04.action )

```
#goal definition
int32 task
---
#result definition
int32 reply_task_id
---
#feedback
int32 useless_feedback
```

When I compile the programs, i get this error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22:0,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/publisher.h:35,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/node_handle.h:32,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /home/serhatsony/catkin_ws/src/qr_drive/src/load_action_03.cpp:12:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void boost::_bi::list2<A1, A2>::operator()(boost::_bi::type<void>, F&, A&, int) [with F = boost::_mfi::mf1<void, LoadActionServer, const boost::shared_ptr<const qr_drive::load_service_04ActionGoal_<std::allocator<void> > >&>; A = boost::_bi::list1<const boost::shared_ptr<const qr_drive::load_service_04Goal_<std::allocator<void> > >&>; A1 = boost::_bi::value<LoadActionServer*>; A2 = boost::arg<1>]’:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:905:50:   required from ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()(A1&&) [with A1 = const boost::shared_ptr<const qr_drive::load_service_04Goal_<std::allocator<void> > >&; R = void; F = boost::_mfi::mf1<void, LoadActionServer, const boost::shared_ptr<const qr_drive::load_service_04ActionGoal_<std::allocator<void> > >&>; L = boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<LoadActionServer*>, boost::arg<1> >; boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type = void]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:159:11:   required from ‘static void boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<FunctionObj, R, T0>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, T0) [with FunctionObj = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, LoadActionServer, const boost::shared_ptr<const qr_drive::load_service_04ActionGoal_<std::allocator<void> > >&>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<LoadActionServer*>, boost::arg<1> > >; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const qr_drive::load_service_04Goal_<std::allocator<void> > >&]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:940:38:   required from ‘void boost::function1<R, T1>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, LoadActionServer, const boost::shared_ptr<const qr_drive::load_service_04ActionGoal_<std::allocator<void> > >&>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<LoadActionServer*>, boost::arg<1> > >; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const qr_drive::load_service_04Goal_<std::allocator<void> > >&]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:728:7:   required from ‘boost::function1<R, T1>::function1(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, LoadActionServer, const boost::shared_ptr<const qr_drive::load_service_04ActionGoal_<std::allocator<void> > >&>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<LoadActionServer*>, boost::arg<1> > >; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const qr_drive::load_service_04Goal_<std::allocator<void> > >&; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1077:16:   required from ‘boost::function<R(T0)>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, LoadActionServer, const boost::shared_ptr<const qr_drive::load_service_04ActionGoal_<std::allocator<void> > >&>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<LoadActionServer*>, boost::arg<1> > >; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const qr_drive::load_service_04Goal_<std::allocator<void> > >&; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/home/serhatsony/catkin_ws/src/qr_drive/src/load_action_03.cpp:32:20:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:313:35: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_mfi::mf1<void, LoadActionServer, const boost::shared_ptr<const qr_drive::load_service_04ActionGoal_<std::allocator<void> > >&>) (LoadActionServer*&, const boost::shared_ptr<const qr_drive::load_service_04Goal_<std::allocator<void> > >&)’
         unwrapper<F>::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_], a[base_type::a2_]);
```

As you can see, the compiler tries to say something about this topic:

```
/home/serhatsony/catkin_ws/src/qr_drive/src/load_action_03.cpp:32:20:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:313:35: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_mfi::mf1<void, LoadActionServer, const boost::shared_ptr<const qr_drive::load_service_04ActionGoal_<std::allocator<void> > >&>) (LoadActionServer*&, const boost::shared_ptr<const qr_drive::load_service_04Goal_<std::allocator<void> > >&)’
         unwrapper<F>::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_], a[base_type::a2_]);
```

I think, my problem is about this section in my action server:

```
 void LoadActionFunc(const qr_drive::load_service_04ActionGoalConstPtr &goal)
```

I have created a few action server in the same package where this program is located too. And they run without any problem. (I mean my CMakeLists.txt and package.xml should be fine for handing with action servers) In addition to that, I can see my action messages has been created successfully. Where am i doing wrong? Any idea or advice?

Thank you in advance.

ROS1 Kinetic Ubuntu 16.04

---

[Originally posted]([https://answers.ros.org/question/383907/action-server-compiler-error-=>-error:-no-match-for-call-to-‘(boost::_mfi......../)](https://answers.ros.org/question/383907/action-server-compiler-error-=%3E-error:-no-match-for-call-to-%E2%80%98(boost::_mfi......../)) by [serhat](https://answers.ros.org/users/64454/serhat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2021-08-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all, I found my problem. With the help of what the compiler says, I focused on this part:
`error: no match for call to ‘(boost`: This compiler error tells us you try to pass wrong data format into a function. Such as:

```
void(string data)
{
  print(data) ; 
}
```

But you try to pass integer variables or data into this func. In my question, we also see same compiler error mentality. After a quick check of my "execute callback func", I realized that I wrote this:

```
void LoadActionFunc(const qr_drive::load_service_04ActionGoalConstPtr &goal)
```

while i should type as follow:

```
void LoadActionFunc(const qr_drive::load_service_06GoalConstPtr &request) ;
```

After this correction, my compiler doesn't throw any error and problem solved.

---

Originally posted by [serhat](https://answers.ros.org/users/64454/serhat/) with karma: 72 on 2021-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1